# Can 3 Vectors ever span $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

If I had: $(0,1)$, $(1,2)$, and $(1,3)$, couldn’t I always set the constant that multiplies the third vector equal to 0, and then the other two vectors could successfully span all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ since they aren’t scalar multiples of each other?

That makes sense to me when I visualize that in my head, but is that wrong? Could that work?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, because it only takes two vectors to span $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: I'm sorry - im burnt out because of finals and my teacher is throwing all this info at us. thank you for clarifying

Comment: Um hmm.  You could take any two vectors that span, that is, a basis, and add to it as many vectors as you like.  The result would still span, but no longer be a basis.

Comment: What would happen if the question asked, "is every vector in R2 in the span of {(0,1), (1,2), (1,3)} is this still true? Is that the same question as I had above?

Comment: It's basically the same question, and the answer is yes.

Comment: One last question - is it accurate to say all 3 of those vectors span R2, or just 2 of them span R2?

Comment: Both are accurate statements.